# How to Change Variable in If Statement. Why does this not work?

Tags: php, html, variables, if-statement

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work. It seems so simple.
It should output this.

Intro,First,Second,Third,First,Second,Third,First,Second,Third
Intro,First,Second,Third,First,Second,Third,First,Second,Third
Intro,First,Second,Third,First,Second,Third,First,Second,Third
Intro,First,Second,Third,First,Second,Third,First,Second,Third ...etc

But it does not see the the $columnnum=0; and after the first line, it just goes keeps going.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$testarray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21);
$columnnum = 0;
foreach ($testarray as $value) {
    $columnnum++;
    if ($columnnum == 1) {
        echo "Intro, ";
    }
    echo "First, ";
    echo "Second, ";
    echo "Third";
    if ($columnnum == 3) {
        $columnum = 0;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo " col: ", $columnnum;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a strange way to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You typoed `$columnnum=0` near the end of the loop.

---

This should be more efficient:

```
echo str_repeat("Intro,".str_repeat("First,Second,Third",3)."<br>",7);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes 10 hours of straight coding gets to you. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Because you missed an 'n' in $columnum

```
$columnum = 0;
```

should be

```
$columnnum = 0;
```